# How to import angular 8 src into ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, angular8

We already developed an project in angular 8. I trying to import the project src into ionic project.

Created an blank ionic project and replacing angular 8 project src than making ionic build facing ionic build issues in angular.

[image]

Is there any way to import angular8 src into ionic6 project

Thanks.

Comment: what error are you facing? i Think its not possible. i haven't tried it but it seems impossible.

Comment: Error log screenshot attached

Comment: Install ionic app script again and try.

Comment: Currently following the steps in https://stack247.wordpress.com/2019/03/11/integrate-ionic-in-existing-angular-project/

Comment: it Worked or Not? let me know.

Comment: The steps (https://stack247.wordpress.com/2019/03/11/integrate-ionic-in-existing-angular-project/) provided is working fine.

Comment: Facing issue on ionic cordova build with the above reference link

Comment: i will try and let you know.